# How to get a custom color in Agar.io

Tags: agar.io

In agar.io, is there a way to get a custom color? I need a certain shade of yellow and I dont know how to get it. I know that there are custom skins, but I have not found anything about colors. I have had the idea of giving myself a custom skin with all 1 color, but the cell's border would stay another color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colors are randomly assigned when you spawn, and there is no way currently to choose your color (even team mode will give you a random shade of your team color).

That said, the game is updated pretty often and the Developer is known to take requests. So in the future you, may be able to set your color, but it might be a good idea to contact the developer regarding the request.